# How can I describe complex json model in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to use Swagger to describe web-api I'm building.
The problem is that I can't understand how to describe complex json object?

For example, how to describe this objects:

```
{
  name: "Jhon",
  address: [
    {
      type: "home",
      line1: "1st street"
    },
    {
       type: "office",
       line1: "2nd street"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The answer is different between Swagger 1.2 and Swagger 2.0. Which one do you plan to use?

Comment: Swagger 2.0. Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for the JSON representation or a YAML one to be used with Swagger-editor? Once I have that information, I can provide you with a relevant snippet.

Comment: I prefer json if possible, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Ron!  How can I set objects length in any array like in address there should be minimum 3 addresses maximum number can be anyone. Thank you.

Comment: even I tried 


 { "type":"array", "items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/image"},"minitems":4 }


 but still i am getting only one image

Comment: @9me - the "minItems" is the solution. If it doesn't work for you in a specific tool (not sure which one you use), I'd suggest opening a ticket on that tool directly.

Comment: @Ron - I am using latest swagger UI tool. I am getting only one item. But in editor(latest) tool i am getting one dynamic form where i can add more items but not in UI with same file.

Comment: Then file a ticket on swagger-ui.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Okay, so based on the comments above, you want the following schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "name" ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "home", "office" ]
            },
            "line1": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I've made a few assumptions to make the sample a bit more complicated, to help in the future.
For the "user" object, I've declared that the "name" field is mandatory. If, for example, you also need the address to be mandatory, you can change the definition to "required": [ "name", "address" ].

We basically use a subset of json-schema to describe the models. Of course not everyone knows it, but it's fairly simple to learn and use.

For the address type you can see I also set the limit to two options - either home or office. You can add anything to that list, or remove the "enum" entirely to remove that constraint.

When the "type" of a property is "array", you need to accompany it with "items" which declares the internal type of the array. In this case, I referenced another definition, but that definition could have been inline as well. It's normally easier to maintain that way, especially if you need the "address" definition alone or within other models.

As requested, the inline version:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "home",
                  "office"
                ]
              },
              "line1": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If you'll be kind enough to also she an example of inline it will be great. Another question is does SwaggerUI support this complex object schema? Because from me test it doesn't.

Comment: I've modified the answer with the inline version.

Comment: As for Swagger-UI, it should support complex schemas. I'd need to see a full example to understand what may be wrong. You can also use our google group for such questions.

Comment: @Ron I know this is late. But can you explain the model for this. Or Ran can you. I'm newbie. How will Swagger change its UI to support this structure

Comment: @nilan59 - I'd suggest posting your question in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket and we'll help there. The comments are not really suitable for that.

Comment: @Ron Its done. Thanks for the directions... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/1YBFMbKm0VY