# Rswag nested objects, rswag syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a project where I have nested objects. I have tried to figure out the correct syntax for nested array. This is something that I have tired (among of the many other things):

```
parameter name: :measurement, in: :body, schema: {
  type: :object,
  properties: {
    measurement_code: { type: :string },
  },
  type: :array_of_objects,
  measure: { type: :array },
  items: {
    value: { type: :integer }
    name: { type: :string }
    id: { type: :integer }
  },
  required: []
}
```

The example data that I am sending:

```
{"measurement_code"=>"918031199-7",
 :measure=>
  [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 8049,
    "name": "Temporibus quam et ipsum blanditiis hic."
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 76060,
    "name": "Sint omnis."
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the exact issue you're encountering with this syntax - error message, warning, etc?

Comment: I think I am too far away form the correct syntax. There is very little documentation in rswag and actual swagger syntax seems to be a bt different.

Comment: Thanks @waldrumpus sending me to debug and google one more round :D. This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206685/how-can-i-describe-complex-json-model-in-swagger/26425272#26425272. Correct solution added to original question.

Comment: Excellent, good job! You can post an answer with your findings yourself and accept it as correct if you like, or vote to close this question as a duplicate if it's too close to the one you found your solution in.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the proposal @waldrumpus. Stack overflow newbie here. First question..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works as the rswag syntax for array of objects:

```
  properties: {
    measurement_code: { type: :string },
    measure: {
      type: :array,
      items: {
        properties: {
          value: { type: :integer },
          name: { type: :string },
          id: { type: :integer }
        }
      },
    },
  }
```